# spring-boot: ip binding type

Tags: java, spring-boot, ip, undertow

I've got a spring boot 3.x project with the following properties:

```
server:
  address: 127.0.0.1
  port: 8080
```

On my server I've got a script to show my IP bindings in a sorted overview. The script is based on `lsof -i -nP | grep LISTEN`. I've got an output like this:

```
java      20001 user  116u  IPv6 0x1a2a27c68a753431      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
```

I'm using undertow as embedded server.

BTW, I'm not a network pro. But I would like to understand why spring boot binds the IP on the type IPV6 instead of IPV4.

I tested it on Ubuntu 22.04 and macOS 13.4.